Omnistudio: provide a default value for a picklist when using custom Apex to populate it
I'm trying to get a default value to populate in a picklist where the values are coming from custom Apex. So far, I've tried to add a default value in the JSON editor in the OmniScript on the Select input properties:
{
  "HTMLTemplateId": "",
  "accessibleInFutureSteps": false,
  "conditionType": "Hide if False",
  "controlWidth": 6,
  "controllingField": {
    "element": "",
    "source": "",
    "type": ""
  },
  "defaultValue": "1",
  "disOnTplt": false,
  "help": false,
  "helpText": "",
  "hide": false,
  "inputWidth": 12,
  "label": "Number of Families",
  "optionSource": {
    "source": "PicklistOptions.testJsonData",
    "type": "Custom"
  },
  "options": [],
  "readOnly": false,
  "repeat": false,
  "repeatClone": false,
  "repeatLimit": null,
  "required": true,
  "show": null,
  "showInputWidth": false
}

but this didn't seem to do anything. I've also tried to add it to what is being returned to the OS like so (also tried with direct boolean values instead of strings):
    [
        {
            "name": 1,
            "value": 1,
            "default": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": 2,
            "value": 2,
            "default": "false"
        },
        {
            "name": 3,
            "value": 3,
            "default": "false"
        },
        {
            "name": 4,
            "value": 4,
            "default": "false" 
        }
    ]

but again, this isn't working either. Our solution so far is similar to this and the apex does indeed populate the picklist, but the default value is missing. Any suggestions?
